# What would be a good strategy to implement functionality similar to facebook 'likes'?

Tags: python, architecture

I have a website where people post comments, pictures, and other content. I want to add a feature that users can like/unlike these items.

I use a database to store all the content.

There are a few approaches I am looking at:

**Method 1:**

1. Add a 'like_count' column to the table, and increment it whenever someone likes an item
2. Add a 'user_likes' table to keep a track that everything the user has liked.

Pros: Simple to implement, minimal queries required.
Cons: The item needs to be refreshed with each change in like count. I have a whole list of items cached, which will break.

**Method 2:**

1. Create a new table 'like_summary' and store the total likes of each item in that table
2. Add a 'user_likes' table to keep a track that everything the user has liked.
3. Cache the like_summary data in memcache, and only flush it if the value changes

Pros: Less load on the main items table, it can be cached without worrying.
Cons: Too many hits on memcache (a page shows 20 items, which needs to be loaded from memcache), might be slow

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question does not make much sense without further information about expected load, access numbers and overall architecture and setup.

Comment: What do you mean by 'implement facebook likes' ? Do you want your website to duplicate this functionality (without any real link to facebook) or do you want some sort of mashup-kludge-integration across websites? Very unclear without more info...

Comment: sorry for being unclear.. here are some more details: 1. Its going to be internal only (so not to be embedded on external websites). 2. You can think of it as a bit analogous to the vote-up/vote-down on stack overflow. 3. I want to make sure that it scales to 500 concurrent page views, with each page containing 25 items with a 'like' count displayed next to it. The overall system is based on Python / Mysql / Memcache,

Answer (score 3):

Just a *crazy* idea: Why not just use Facebook's [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) button? Then, not only do you get that functionality for free, but you can increase the traffic to your website by a huge amount with Facebook wall posts: "This person likes this site".

Comment: This is for internal use on a website, the functionality is similar to facebook's like button but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

One relation table that does a many-to-many mapping between user and item should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You will actually only need the user_likes table. The like_count is calculated from that table. You will only need to store that if you need to gain performance, but since you're using memcached, It may be a good idea to not store the aggregated value in the database, but store it only in memcached.

Comment: Good point. I have been thinking about storing the likes count in memcache, but am wondering how much performance hit will it have as compared to loading everything in a single SQL statement. For a page with 25 'likeable' entities, the options will be to either have 25 memcache requests a single sql statement.

Comment: Of course you will have the query cache in MySQL, but its use is limited. Memcache id very fast, and you will be able to retreive anywhere from tens to hundreds of items in the time to execute a single small query.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. If i warm up the memcache with some of the popular 'counts', then it should be able to do quite well. Another reason why I wanted to store the likes in database was so that I can do stuff like 'most liked'. I can still store the likes count in database but use it for batch processing.